# RegEx: Match URL including tilde

Tags: php, regex

I need to match relative URLs in my code, and replace it with absolute URLs. In these relative URLs there is a `~` character, which I can't seem to match.

```
$page = preg_replace('/src="(\/)?([\w_\-\/\.\?&=@%#]*)"/i','src="' . $url . '$2"', $page);
$page = preg_replace('/href="(\/)?([\w_\-\/\.\?&=@%#]*)"/i','href="' . $url . '$2"', $page);
```

This should replace my URLs, but it doesn't work with these URLs:

- https://www.domain.dk/~/media/2561BD6AFBD64402877E4ACED01F97FD.ashx
- /cassette.axd/stylesheet/fdbdaa59cb97b35f06f65fd41cb60caa3975cc0f/forbrug-rwd_(max-width
  767px)

How is that?

Answer (score 0):

I would use this regex:

```
(?:src="|href=")(?!http)\/?(.+?)"
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/rRKJzCTPG-XSdPXm)

This will allow you to catch all URLs in `src` or `href` attributes, which doesn't start by `http` (and it'll care of the presence or not of a leading slash):

```
$page = preg_replace('/(?:src="|href=")(?!http)\/?(.+)"/i', $url . '$1', $page);
```

Comment: Great. Thanks. But I get an error: `Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '('` ... Could something be misformatted?

Comment: If the input is: `<a href="../../image.jpg">Link</a><img src="/image.jpg" />` then the output will be: `<a http:="" www.domain.dk="" ..="" image.jpg"="">Link</a>`. Do you know why?

Comment: Ya, we need to use `(.+?)` instead of `(.+)`

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't work. The replace has removed the "href" and "src"... and the value is without "/" and ":"

Comment: When I add this, it kinda works.  `$page = preg_replace('/(?:href=")(?!http)\/?(.+?)"/i', 'href="' . $url . '$1' . '"', $page);` The `/~/` still doesn't work. It should replace the `/~/` with the domain only, without subfolder.

Answer (score 0):

> The `/~/` still doesn't work. It should replace the `/~/` with the domain
>   only, without subfolder.

It's probably easiest if we do this in an extra replacement step afterwards.

```
$domain = 'www.domain.dk';
$page = preg_replace("#($domain/)~/#", '$1', $page);
```